# Wiggling of dryer cord turns power to dryer off & on

Tags: electrical, dryer

When my whirlpool dryer cord is moved or touched my dryer will shut off and say power failure and won’t do anything. If I wiggle or reposition the cord the dryer will turn back on and say power failure and will restart.

Comment: Yeah, don't do that.

Comment: Downvoted because there is no question here, no research, and no description of the power cord.

Answer (score 8):

Replace the cord.  It probably has a broken wire.

Check the receptacle/outlet for loose wire connection also when you have the breaker turned off.

Moving/wiggling of a cord to get power again is the classic test for a broken wire inside of the cord.

You are dealing with 240 volts and 30 amps of power.  Fix it now.

Answer (score 4):

That is very dangerous. A poor contact like that can start *series arcing*, which will create a tremendous amount of heat and fire.  Depending on where the problem is, it can start a fire in the walls.

- The problem may be internal to the plug itself - replace the dryer cord, they are commodity items.
- it may be in the contacts between plug and socket - replace the deteriorated item, typically a socket.
- it may be the terminals where the wires attach to the socket - in the 2000s the  data proved that screw torque matters, even on smaller 15-50A terminals (this was well known on larger terminals), and NEC was amended in 2014 to require torque screwdrivers be used on any screw which specifies a torque.  Don't just re-torque — if torque is suspect, unhook, inspect, clean and/or replace.

While we're addressing this, obsolete 3-wire range and dryer connections are dangerous.  If the neutral wire gets loose, it energizes the chassis of the machine.  The dryer is kind enough to stop working, but on a range you would never know it since only the oven light is affected.  If you have a 4-wire supply cable, or can retrofit a #10 ground wire, or can install a GFCI breaker to protect the circuit, we advise switching to 4-wire socket and cord.